# Split a txt file into an array and find elements within the array

Tags: java

Hello basically my aim is to read a `txt` file store it within an array and print the array element after the method argument. the text file is formated as shown (a space between each string on a line)

```
alan 1000

lee 20

rodney 28
```

e.g. if my argument was `lee`, the method should print out `20`. If `rodney` then `28`

```
public class practice
{
public void dataReader(String fName, String pname)
{
    try
    {
      FileReader fr=new FileReader(fName);
      BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);

      String[] a={};
      String line= br.readLine();


      while(line !=null)
      {
           a= line.split(" "); // deliminator white space
      }

      for(int i=0; i <a.length; i++)
      {
          if(a[i].equals(pname))
          {
              System.out.println(a[i]+1);
          }
      }
    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Use formatting, Java classes start with upper-case letter (convention)

Comment: If this is homework it should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 5):

The code you posted is not working because you only ever read the first line, then loop over that line forever.

Your code, trimmed and annotated:

```
String line= br.readLine(); // returns the first line of the file

while(line !=null) { // checks if the line is null - it's not at the first line
    a= line.split(" "); // deliminator white space
}
// we never get here, because nowhere in the loop do we set line to null
```

You need to call `br.readLine()` in a loop until it returns null, something like this:

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fName));

String line= br.readLine(); // reads the first line, or nothing

while(line != null) {
    a= line.split(" "); // deliminator white space
    String[] arr = line.split("\\s+"); // splits a string by any amount of whitespace
    if(arr.length >= 2 && arr[0].equals(lookup)) {
        System.out.println(arr[1]);
    }

    line = br.readLine(); // this will eventually set line to null, terminating the loop
}
```

The for loop in your original code will not work, if you ever hit it your output would be `lee1` or `rodney1` respectively.  If you changed it to `arr[i+1]` instead, which I assume you were trying to do, it would crash with an IndexOutOfBoundsException if ever the last item in the array matched `pname`.

---

**Orginal Answer**

This is an ideal use case for a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).  It "scans" a string or file for the contents you're looking for, dramatically simplifying file parsing for many use cases, in particular whitespace-delimited files.

```
public void searchFile(String fName, String lookup){
  Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fName));
  // Assumes the file has two "words" per line
  while(in.hasNext()){
    String name = in.next();
    String number = in.next():
    if(name.equals(lookup){
      System.out.println(number);
    }
  }
}
```

If you cannot use scanner to parse each line, you can still use it to simplify reading each line, and then do whatever more complex parsing of the line needs to be done, like so:

```
public void searchFile2(String fName, String lookup){
  Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fName));
  while(in.hasNextLine()){
    String line = in.nextLine();
    String[] arr = line.split("\\s+"); // splits a string by any amount of whitespace
    if(arr[0].equals(lookup)){
      System.out.println(arr[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

As an aside, if you know the names will be unique, you can use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (specifically, a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)) to store and lookup mappings like names to numbers efficiently.  So instead of having a method which takes a filename and a name to lookup, you have a method which parses the file and returns a mapping of *all* names to numbers, then you can simply call `map.get("name")` on the returned map to get a given person's number efficiently, without having to re-read the file every time.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Dictionary object

```
Dictionary<String, Integer> wordPairs = new Dictionary<String, Integer>();
while(br.ReadLine())
{
    wordPairs.put(a[0], Integer.parseInt(a[1]));
}
```

To get the number, you simply lookup in the dictionary by the key name.

```
public int getNumber(string name)
{
    return wordPairs.get(name);
}
```

Comment: Any one of the Map-type collections would work fine for this.

Comment: Note that [Dictionary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html) is obsolete, and should not be used.  Objects implementing [java.util.Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) should be used instead.  Additionally, you should avoid starting method and variable names with upper case letters, as they can be easily confused with class names.  Finally, you cannot use `int` in a generic, you must use the wrapper class `Integer`.

Comment: thanks for the help guys but the task requires use of line.split. i agree scanner would be the best option however in this case i cannot use it

Comment: @mathew it would be helpful if you clarified exactly what issue you are struggling with. I have posted an alternative that uses `String.split()` in my answer.

Comment: thanks again although the use of scanner is completly not allowed as the task specifies. Im just wondering why the code i had written does not work, by my understanding it reads each line and splits each string  in the array, and attempts to search through the array.

Comment: Understood.  In the future, please try to provide more details about what issue(s) you're stuck on, rather than just explaining the problem as a whole.  See my answer for more.

Comment: Would a dictionary object work if you have a file that has two keys that you need to search another file with but you can discard the other values. I have to find if there is a match in both files and write those two records to a file, then if key in File1 but not in File2 and then if in File2 and not in File1.